# I want to store and display highScore value on local device with .NET MAUI MVVM. Where and with what code snippet can I do this?

Tags: c#, .net, maui, android-mvvm, maui-community-toolkit

I'm developing a simple math practice game with .NET MAUI MVVM. I want the highScore value on the main page of the game to be updated after I close the application and re-enter it every time I play. What page and how can I do this?

PlayerModal.cs

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MauiApp2.Models
{
    public partial class PlayerModal : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        int score;
        [ObservableProperty]
        int highScore;
        [ObservableProperty]
        int timeReaming;
        [ObservableProperty]
        int correctAnswer;
        [ObservableProperty]
        string answer;
        [ObservableProperty]
        string question;
    }
}
```

MultiplicationPageViewModel.cs

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using MauiApp2.Models;
using MauiApp2.Services;
using MauiApp2.Views;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MauiApp2.ViewModels
{
    public partial class MultiplicationPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<PlayerModal> PlayerDetails { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<PlayerModal>();
        public PlayerModal playerModal { get; set; } = BaseViewModel.PlayerModal;
        public ICommand SubmitAnswerCommand { get; }
        public MultiplicationPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
        {
            
            playerModal.Score = 0;
            playerModal.TimeReaming= 60;
            SubmitAnswerCommand = new Command(SubmitAnswer);

            // Create a question as an example
            GenerateQuestion();
            // Start the timer
            StartTimer();
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public void GenerateQuestion()
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int number1 = random.Next(1, 11); // a random number between 1 and 10
            int number2 = random.Next(1, 11); // a random number between 1 and 10

            // playerModal.Answer = (number1 * number2).ToString(); Automatic Answer
            playerModal.Question = $"{number1} x {number2}"; 
            playerModal.CorrectAnswer = number1 * number2;
        }
        public async void StartTimer()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000); // wait 1 sec
                playerModal.TimeReaming--;

                if (playerModal.TimeReaming == 0)
                {
                    GameOver(); // Finish the game when time is up
                    playerModal.TimeReaming = 60;
                }
            }
        }

        public void SubmitAnswer()
        {
            if (int.TryParse(playerModal.Answer, out int userAnswer))
            {
                int correctAnswer = playerModal.CorrectAnswer;
                if (userAnswer == correctAnswer)
                {
                    playerModal.Score += 10;
                    playerModal.TimeReaming += 5;

                }
                else
                {
                    playerModal.Score -= 10;
                    playerModal.TimeReaming -= 55;

                    // Negative score and time control
                    if (playerModal.Score < 0)
                    {
                        playerModal.Score = 0;
                    }
                    if (playerModal.TimeReaming <= 0)
                    {
                        GameOver();
                        playerModal.TimeReaming = 60;
                    }
                }

                GenerateQuestion();
            }

            playerModal.Answer = "";

        }

        public void GameOver()
        {
            // Check earned score and update new high score
            if (playerModal.Score > playerModal.HighScore)
            {
                playerModal.HighScore = playerModal.Score;

                // Save the high score to preferences
                Preferences.Default.Set("HighScore", playerModal.HighScore);

            }

            NavigationService.NavigateToAsync(nameof(GameOverPage));
        }
    }
}
```

HomePageViewModel.cs

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using MauiApp2.Models;
using MauiApp2.Services;
using MauiApp2.Views;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MauiApp2.ViewModels
{
    public partial class HomePageViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<PlayerModal> PlayerDetails { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<PlayerModal>();
        public PlayerModal playerModal { get; set; } = BaseViewModel.PlayerModal;
        public HomePageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
        {
            // Load the high score from preferences
            int highScore = Preferences.Default.Get("HighScore", 0);

            // Set the high score on the view model
            playerModal.HighScore = highScore;
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public void Play()
        {
            NavigationService.NavigateToAsync(nameof(SelectionPage));
        }
    }
}
```

HomePage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MauiApp2.ViewModels"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MauiApp2.Models"
             x:Class="MauiApp2.Views.HomePage"
             x:DataType="viewModels:HomePageViewModel"
             Title="Home">
    <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Label 
            Text="MATH GAME"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" 
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            FontSize="50"/>
        <Label 
            Text="High Score"
            Margin="0,15,0,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" 
            FontAttributes="None"
            FontSize="40"/>
        <Label 
            Text="{Binding playerModal.HighScore}"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" 
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            FontSize="30"/>
        <Button Text="Play"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                FontSize="20"
                Margin="90,30,90,0"
                Command="{Binding PlayCommand}"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/preferences?tabs=android)

```
Preferences.Default.Set("HighScore", value);
```

and

```
int highScore = Preferences.Default.Get("HighScore", 0);
```

Comment: where should i use this @Jason

Comment: wherever you want to save and then retrieve the values

Comment: Since I want to use it when the game is over, I used it under the ```GameOver()``` Method, but it didn't work. Where do you think I should use it? @Jason

Comment: nowhere in your code are you loading the value from Preferences, so how can you tell it's not working?

Comment: I think I understood what you said and i update ```GameOver()``` Method, but it still didn't work. When I reopen the application, my highScore shows 0, even though it goes up. @Jason

Comment: you have to **load the saved value** when your app starts or your page loads.  That is why there is a `Set` and a `Get` method

Comment: Do I need to change it the other way around? @Jason

Comment: "when your app starts or your page loads" - is that what you are doing?

Comment: when i apps starts

Comment: you are only doing it in `GameOver`

Comment: So where exactly should I use it? @Jason

Comment: How about the constructor of your page or VM?

Comment: I solved the problem and update question. I get the highest score from the user in the ```GameOver()``` method and load it to the screen whenever I enter the game in ```HomePageViewModel.cs``` @Jason